# full content for mail body cannot send using <a href='mailto:{$to}?subject={$subject}&body={$body}'>

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-7

i'm in trouble with passing multiple lines through mailto: link.
in case of small content message body "mailto" link is clickable and also open window for Outlook default mail reader.
But in case of large content message body ,the mailto link couldnt clickable and also in some case full body content cannot passed to mail box, it take only limited content size. how solve this issue in PHP and Drupal.
can you suggest any other method for this.

my code is following:-

```
$to= "XXX@mail.com";
$subject = "XXX"
$body = str_replace( array( '\'', '&','amp;','<p>','</p>','nbsp'), ' ', $str_body);
$body = htmlspecialchars($body);

$page.="<div>";
$page.= "<a href='mailto:{$to}?subject={$subject}&body={$body}'>"; 
$page.="</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlencode()` on the $subject, $body

```
$to= "XXX@mail.com";
$subject = urlencode("XXX");
$body = strip_tags($str_body); // use strip tags
$body = urlencode(htmlspecialchars($body));
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion. But it also not worked for body having large amount of data. can you suggest any other method for in "onclick" to open Outlook default mail reader and  pass subject and body to it.

Comment: default mail app is decided by OS, webpage cant force it to open in outlook (maybe IE can)

Comment: Issue still exist.In case of mail body large amount of data,even the link can not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of mailto link depends on the browser. There is no way you can influence it. Also you are at the mercy of the special configuration of the client computer : the browser passes the data in the link to the default email account of the default email software. This might work or not.

If you want to have control over the email sent, your page must POST the data on the server and you have to send it using PHP either using the mail() function or a mailer library.